# Navigation item title view - same for all pushed view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationitem

How can you keep navigation item title view same for all pushed view controllers?

E.g. I'd like to set title view to a logo that should be visible for all screens.

```
UIImage *logoImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navigation-bar-logo"];
UIImageView *titleLogo = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:logoImage];
self.navigationItem.titleView = titleLogo;
```

If I set it for each view controller individually, it looks strange with the iOS7 navigation bar animation.

Answer (score -1):

One way to do this is to use UINavigationItem.titleView and 
UINavigationItem.rightBarButtonItem. Like this :

```
viewController.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage.png"]];
UIBarButtonItem * item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage2.jpg"]]];    
viewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = item;
```

Here I am using UIImageView as custom view, but it can be UIButton with custom image.

Another way which I suggest you is that without using a viewController

```
// Create your image
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"logo.png"];
UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: image];

// set the text view to the image view
self.navigationItem.titleView = imageview;
```

Hopefully this info will helps you. Cheers :)

Comment: This is just explaining how to adjust the titleView of an individual view controller, something the OP says they are already doing and do not like the result of, it doesn't address the actual question.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to show a Navigation item title view - same for all pushed view controllers

- Make a ViewController as ParentViewController and all other
  ViewController as the  child of that .Then what ever design You will do in ParentVC ,It will reflect in Child VC.

Below is the example .
 In appDelegate Class,

```
    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[WARootViewController alloc]init]];
self.window.rootViewController = nav;
```

In the ViewController ,Set the imageView Frame(optional,You can give your desired) and Image Name(mention the extension if logoImage is giving NULL memory).

```
    UIImage *logoImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navigation-bar-logo.jpg"];
UIImageView *titleLogo = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:logoImage];
titleLogo.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 30);
self.navigationItem.titleView = titleLogo;
```

- Make Rest of the ViewControllers as child of WARootViewControllers

  ```
  #import "WARootViewController.h"
  @interface WAFirstViewController : WARootViewController

  #import "WARootViewController.h"
  @interface WASecondViewController : WARootViewController
  ```

Comment: These are not parent / child view controllers, they are subclasses, this is an important distinction. This also does not address the problem of the OP as these are still setting each view controller's titleView individually making it look weird when the new controller is pushed.