# How to keep a Navigation Button in Navigation Bar - iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, navigation, uinavigationbar

Please help! I am trying to place a Bar Button Item to a Navigation Bar and I would like the button to stay there between page transition.  Is there any way to make this happen?

I have tried just adding the same button in the new View Controller's navigation bar, but it looks funny.  It keeps the animation as if the button did not stay in place.

Thanks!

Comment: If anyone has a link to a sample project, that would be great!

Comment: I found the solution! 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22396066/navigation-item-title-view-same-for-all-pushed-view-controllers